# is memcache slowing down my website?

Tags: caching

Hi I have a brand new website, the upload time was around 2 seconds and after installing Memcache it s around 10 seconds, what coulds be causing this issue? 
website is in drupal6

Answer (score 0):

I can not post an comment?

Anyway, there is not much information given about the hardware, settings etc. so from that point off its hard to say.

You might wanna retrace your steps if you are sure the uploadtime increased with 500 percent. Then you know if Memcache caused any problems, what ever the result is please update the question with more specific information.